# MySQL Read lock and query performance analyses

Tags: mysql, performance, locking, mysql-5.7, query-performance

I've a table with the following structure.

```
CREATE TABLE `wallet_details` (
  `id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_status` (`status`(3))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It contains around 30 Million rows.

I need to run the following query on it:

```
select * from my_table where `status` = "UNASSIGNED" limit 1 for update
```

Following is the explain output of it:

```
mysql> explain select * from my_table where `status` = "UNASSIGNED" limit 1 for update;
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows     | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | my_table       | NULL       | ref  | idx_status    | idx_status | 11      | const | 12898668 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+----------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.09 sec)
```

The above query is not scaling very much and I wanted to understand how the above works, at which stage is the query behaving undesirably/heavily, and how can I improve its performance.

Few of my questions are:

1. Would the query run through all of the 12 million rows before fetching the final row (see query has `limit 1` condition)?
2. On how many rows would the read lock be on?

Answer (score 1):

- Don't use "prefix indexes" (`status(3)`); they usually hurt more than they help.
- Shrink the table size...
- What kind of values are in `id VARCHAR(32)`.  (It is unusually to have such a bulky `PRIMARY KEY`.)
- Change `status` from a multi-byte varchar to a 1-byte `ENUM`.
- If there are other columns or indexes in the table, we need to see them in order to understand whether there are side issues.
- What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How much RAM do you have?
- The query will (based on the `EXPLAIN`) scan through the table until it finds the first entry with "UNASSIGNED".  Without knowing the distribution of the data, I can't say when that would occur.
- Eliminating the prefixing *may* speed things up.
- Saying `SELECT id` instead of `SELECT *` *may* speed things up.
- (I don't know how whether the rows before the first "UNASSIGNED" will be locked.)

Comment: You didn't say anything about the last 2 questions I asked. Any thoughts on them?

Comment: I added some on.  At least get rid of the prefiixing and `*`.